# Location accuracy of 500, why?

Tags: android, location, android-geofence

Is it normal to have 500 accuracy with Wifi and GPS activated since I am trying to implement Location and Geofence?

I think it is a little weird...
But I would like to have some feedback relatively to that.

I'm using `FusedLocationApi` to retrieve the information about the Location.

Comment: Yes it's normal. GPS is funky

Comment: The regular GPS chips are fairly inaccurate, I think it's up to a 30m error. There's a new one in production that's accurate within 30 cm, but there are still multiple GPS chips. This is a hardware issue and it isn't one that's going to be fixed any time soon

Comment: @Zoe  Sometimes the location accuracy is 20 and sometimes it is 500... Which is not really good for geofencing in this case....

Comment: What do you expect? We're talking about pinpointing a single point on the planet using satellites in space. There are a ton of reasons why it's off, you could be having bad reception, you're somewhere that makes it hard to track (like a tunnel). It varies for a load of reasons, you can't expect it to be extremely accurate at all times

Comment: @Zoe Ok thank you for the information ! :)